# Magento 2: can't ship order in the backend

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

I've just migrated my Magento 1.9 data to Magento 2.3.1.

Everything works well, but in certain circonstances, I can't ship the order in the back end.

Let's take an example.

I place an order for a product that has stock = 0 but where backorder is configured as "Allow quantity below 0".

So the order is placed without any problem.

Now when trying to ship this order, I have the following message:

**Source item not found by source code: default and sku: Jupon-Vivianna-H2-220cm-Ivoire-50 (4XL).**

Here how this product looks like:
[image]

First guess was salable quantity is blank, so I went on Stores > Configuration > Inventory

And to put a Negative amount in the Out-of-Stock Threshold area (as suggested here (https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html)

[image]

Now here how the product looks like now:

[image]

But when trying to ship the order after this configuration is done, I have now another error message:

**Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity.**

[image]

Already spent few days searching, modifying the configuration.... but still I'm not able to ship the order.

Note that when a configurable product has stock in real, I can ship. 
It is only when stock is 0 with backorder on that I can't ship the order.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

PS: I was before testing that on Magento 2.3.0, and had the same issue.

Comment: I just updated my site to Magento 2.3.1 and on one specific order, when I try to ship, I get "Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity." Did you find a way to override this?

Comment: No... still having the issue and don't know how to solve that. It is ridiculous not being able to ship backorder orders in M2...

Comment: Does anyone has figured out how to solve that ? 

Basically, anyone using backorders should be not be able to ship the orders... or maybe I miss something....

Comment: It looks like the bug, but the Magento team doesn't think so.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this? There is a legitim reason for shipping when qty is 0 or less: Scenario: qty of an item is -3, we receive 2 pc from vendor and change stock qty to -1. But we are not able to create shipment for the two we received due to -1 in stock.

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution in settings for this problem as far as I'm aware. Here is a solution you can use for a Magento 2.3.6 with MSI: create a module and use an observer. Let's say we call our module Vendor_AlwaysShip. It would have an event for sales_order_shipment_save_before:

```
<event name="sales_order_shipment_save_before">
  <observer name="orderAlwaysShip" instance="Vendor\AlwaysShip\Observer\AlwaysShipOrder"/> 
</event>
```

your class AlwaysShipOrder could have a Config setting in the backend but for simplicity I will leave that out here.

```
namespace Vendor\AlwaysShip\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AlwaysShipOrder implements ObserverInterface{
    protected $stockState;
    protected $sourceItemsSaveInterface;
    protected $sourceItemFactory;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState,
       \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface $sourceItemsSaveInterface,
       \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterfaceFactory $sourceItemFactory
    )
    {
        $this->stockState = $stockState;
        $this->sourceItemsSaveInterface = $sourceItemsSaveInterface;
        $this->sourceItemFactory = $sourceItemFactory;
    } 

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $items = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment()->getAllItems();
           if($items) {
             foreach ($items as $item) {
               $productId = $item->getProductId();
               $qty = $this->stockState->getStockQty($productId);
               $itemQty = $item->getQty();
               if ($qty < $itemQty) {
                 $sourceItem = $this->sourceItemFactory->create();
                 $sourceItem->setSourceCode('default');
                 $sourceItem->setSku($item->getSku());
                 $sourceItem->setQuantity($itemQty);
                 $sourceItem->setStatus(1);
                 $this->sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

What the above does is simply check if the amount to ship is available, if not then it just adds the amount needed to the MSI (Multi Source Inventory) so the order can be shipped (hence the name AlwaysShip).

You can even use the registry or a cookie to save the original qty and use another event (sales_order_shipment_save_after) to set the (MSI) qty back to its original qty. In my case this was not needed as long as the qty was 0 again after shipment if it was not in stock before.

Comment: This looks particularly useful for us. Is this packaged as a module anywhere? Thanks