# How to ship Out of Stock products (backorders)?

Tags: magento2, stock, out-of-stock, manage-stock

How could I ship out of stock products (backorders)?

> I see the error: Not all of your products are available in the requested quantity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your settings are and what Magento 2 version you are running (for instance do you use MSI) but I have posted an answer to a similar question on [Magento 2: can't ship order in the backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269982/magento-2-cant-ship-order-in-the-backend/) maybe it can help.